# Validity of the Lyapunov exponent approximation

Tags: classical-mechanics, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems

I was trying to get the Lyapunov exponent for some dynamical nonlinear systems and found that it is not true (as I had expected) that the distance between two trajectories with slightly different initial conditions *always* grows exponentially (to a good approximation).

Instead I found (for the logistical equation and the Lorenz system) that the logarithmic plot of the distance between trajectories is constant at the start, then goes linear (i.e. exponential) and then goes back to constant.

Why is this? The only condition I've found for the Lyapunov approximation to work is that the system must be linearizable. Why does the approximation fail in some intervals of time?

Comment: *Instead I found (for the logistical equation and the Lorenz system) that the logarithmic plot of the distance between trajectories is constant at the start* – This should not happen and I cannot confirm this experimentally. Can you show your data or elaborate how you acquired them?

Comment: What happens late doesn't need to obey conditions obtained from linear approximations. At this time nonlinear effects can completely take over. This is sometimes called saturation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is approximately constant near the beginning because at very short timescales, the transformation of the phase space induced by the time evolution is basically a deformation where the distances change by a factor of $O(1)$.

The middle phase is when the chaos is actually growing  and the distances are growing exponentially.

At the end, at very long timescales, the maximum possible distance is basically reached and equilibrium is reached so the distance has nowhere to grow further.

Comment: *the transformation of the phase space induced by the time evolution is basically a deformation where the distances change by a factor of $O(1)$.* – 1) $O(1)$ in relation to what? 2) Assuming that you are talking about a constant fatcor: If you regard infinitesimal steps of temporal evolution and the distances change by a constant factor each step, you get exponential growth. 3) You are trying to explain a phenomenon, which does not exist. (See my comment on the question.)

Answer (score 2):

> Instead I found (for the logistical equation and the Lorenz system) that the logarithmic plot of the distance between trajectories is constant at the start

This should not happen and I cannot confirm this. Here is the separation of two trajectories I get for the logistic map (averaged over 10000 realisations):

[image: Lyapunov plot for logistic map]

And here is the same for the Lorenz system:

[image: Lyapunov plot for Lorenz system]

The initial higher slope for the Lorenz system is likely due to an initial displacement near the separatrix, i.e., a region where non-linearity plays a role at very small length scales. See, e.g., [Wolf et al](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0167-2789(85)90011-9). In fact, the Lorenz system is not the best system to start calculating Lyapunov exponents with the Wolf method.

Finally note that for many systems, it takes some time for the separation to align itself to the direction of largest growth, and until this has happened, the separation may grow slower or even shrink. Still, it should not be constant, and this does neither apply to the logistic map (as there is only one direction) nor to the Lorenz system (due to the effect mentioned in the last paragraph.

> The only condition I've found for the Lyapunov approximation to work is that the system must be linearizable.

But the linearisability must hold on the length scale of the distance of trajectories. As the systems are non-linear, a length scale on which linearisability is not given anymore must inevitably exist. Often, this length scale corresponds to the size of the attractor, when trajectories begin to approach each other again due to the finite size of the attractor. However, for certain systems, it may be a smaller length scale.

Note that more advanced methods of calculating the Lyapunov exponent (e.g., [Benettin et al.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02128236)’s) solve this problem by only working with infinitesimal separations.

Comment: The short-time deviation from the exponential profile in the middle that was reported by the OP does exist, see e.g. a paper about Ehrenfest times etc. https://arxiv.org/abs/nlin/0111042 - Also, when chaos is due to collisions etc., the free mean path needs to be overcome before the chaos grows.

Comment: 1) The OP reported a deviation from an exponential profile in the beginning, not in the middle. 2) I do not doubt that there are systems exhibiting the described effect, but the OP reported this phenomenon for two specific, clearly defined systems without any quantum effects or collision-based dynamics. (If you can show me how to see such an effect in either of those systems, I would be very interested in that.) 3) The linked paper is about time scales for which classical approximations hold, not about scales of separation of trajectories for which linear approximations hold.

Comment: @LubošMotl: *Also, when chaos is due to collisions etc., the free mean path needs to be overcome before the chaos grows.* – That’s also wrong. If you look at the average (and you have to, otherwise the mean free path is meaningless), you see chaos instantly, as you will find arbitrarily short free paths for some initial conditions.